# Zend regex validator difficulty

Tags: zend-framework, preg-match

I want to allow only the following characters in a string: digits, parentheses and the plus sign, which is [0-9] ( ) +

I can't seem to get a combination to get the validator to return true, the only option seems to be an list of every other possible character that's NOT allowed... which would make for a large list!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^[0-9()+]*$/
```

The regex I gave you there also accepts the empty string. If you want to disallow empty then change the `*` near the end to a `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to slash-escape parens and the plus, because they have special meanings in regex:

```
/^[\d\(\)\+]+$/
```

Comment: I knew to escape the parens and plus... I was missing the ^ and $ from the beginning and end, I didn't know why they were needed. Thanks.